# Design creational pattern suggestion

Tags: java, javascript, design-patterns

Does exist a creational pattern where I define  the father class and every time I need an its child  I can call  its method to create them?

For example (meta-language):

```
class father (){
   method1() {
   new child1();
  }
}
class child1 extend father (){}
```

I need it because I know for sure that in my code I will use the father class, but the child class will be defined only on some button click and I need to use property of father class.

Comment: You can take a look at the creational patterns given : http://www.dofactory.com/net/design-patterns

Comment: Does anyone can explain me the reason of downvote?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why do you want to do that?
Maybe you want to use the Factory Pattern, and remove from the parente class the creation of child instances?

regards,
José Cruz